# Is swapping uint32 for uint64 benign other than (possibly) memory usage?

Tags: c, r, md5, digest

## Background

I recently found that `md5` hashes on large `R` objects using the `digest` package did not change when making small changes. This appears to be due to some 32 bit counter variables getting overflowed and the algorithm missing the changed portion of the file.

Using the current development version of `digest` on Linux, hashes notice these small changes on large files whereas on Windows, these small changes get missed.

I made the following changes to the current dev version, which swaps a few `unsigned long int` (`unit32`) variables for `unsigned long long int` (`uint64`) variables:

https://github.com/eddelbuettel/digest/compare/master...kendonB:testmd5

and now on Windows the problem is fixed and the hashes notice the changes.

## Question

Is swapping out these 32-bit integer variables for 64-bit integer variables benign? Will anything get ruined on 32-bit systems? On obscure systems? Can anything go wrong?

### Further background

https://github.com/eddelbuettel/digest/issues/97

Comment: does the uint32 wrap around?  if so then it matters, if it doesnt than the only change i could think of would be using 2 times the memory.

Comment: I presume that the uint32 wraps around, so that the `md5` hash (incorrectly) starts digesting the start of the object again. This is the behavior I want to avoid, of course.

Answer (score 0):

On a 32-bit system, a 64-bit integer is usually implemented using two 32-bit registers. 
Operations on such an integer result in two instructions for load and store. For something like addition, add with carry is used.
This is something the compiler takes care of.

You should only make sure that the compiler you are using supports such a type.

For example, the signed and unsigned versions of `long long int` (which should be at least 64 bits) were introduced in C99. So you should use a compiler has support for this feature of the C99 standard.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. So, if the compiler supports C99, switching out the 32 bit integers for 64 bit integers should 1) fix the bug, and 2) not ruin anything else other than memory usage?

Comment: I do not know if the bug is only due to the overflow. If it is, then it would be fixed. But then it should also be tested well before release.

Comment: How would one test if it's due to the overflow or not?

Comment: @kennyB test if the `length parameter is larger than 32 bits?

Answer (score 0):

The MD5 hash of a string is a unique well-defined value, which is a vital feature of the MD5 hash. It allows it to be used for verification. (Although cryptographic use of MD5 has been deprecated for some time.)

So if a particular library produces the wrong hash value, that's a bug, and a pretty serious one, and it should be reported as such to the package author. There are reference implementations of the MD5 hash which can be used to obtain the correct hash value, but the `md5sum` command is highly likely to be correct as well, which might be a simpler check.

It is certainly possible that the bug in question, if you can verify that it is a bug, is the result of an unexpected 32-bit integer overflow. But modifying crypto libraries is not a casual acitvity, even buggy implementations of deprecated alogorithms. "It seems to work" is usually not an adequate algorithm validation. I would caution against using an unvalidated modification. But it's a useful hint for the library maintainer.

Comment: Can you make this answer a bit more constructive? e.g. how would one validate a modification of an md5 algorithm? To be clear in the above case, the _same_ code disagrees across Windows (compiled with gcc 4.9.3) and Linux (compiled with a more modern gcc). How would one prevent 32-bit integer overflow if not by swapping out for longer integer types?

Comment: @kennyb: at a minimum, you would need to check that  the modified code computes the correct hash codes for a reasonable number of test cases. I would also want to construct a good argument that the integer overflow happens and disrupts the algorithm, which would be a lot easier for whoever wrote the code. In other words, I'd be looking for a more substantive claim than "with thus modification, the hashes for X and Y are now different." Certainly you would fix overflow by using a wider type, but there might also be some use of a value known to have been reduced modulo 2^32.

Comment: In other words, I don't consider myself sufficiently knowledgeable about MD5 to render public judgement about the validity of an unreviewed patch. Maybe someone else here is, but in general terms for crypto software, I'd want the patch to be reviewed by the author and/or some crypto experts. There is a crypto stackexchange, fwiw.